# Chronos cannot speak French

Tags: shell

I changed `chronos-text-to-speech-notify` acording to https://github.com/dxknight/chronos/issues/2.

My Chronos config includes this:

> (setq chronos-text-to-speech-program-parameters  "-s 50 -k 1 -a 50 -v mb/mb-fr1" ).

The command

> (chronos-add-timer "0:0:1" "Coucou, je parle français" nil)

is supposed to speak the message with a French voice, but it doesn't (default English voice only)

Chronos sent  this shell command:

> espeak \"-s 50 -k 1 -a 50 -v mb/mb-fr1\" \"20:44 Coucou, je parle français\"

which returned

> Failed to read voice 'mb/mb-fr1"'

This shell command works fine, however:

> ```
> espeak -s 50 -k 1 -a 50 -v mb/mb-fr1 "20:44 Coucou, je parle français"
> ```

This sounds like a bug, but I haven't succeeded in fixing it.

Comment: Maybe give a link for, and a short description of, Chronos?

Comment: What is the *question*? So far, this risks being closed as unclear. Please pose an explicit question. Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure what the *fix* is, but I suspect there's a difference between `espeak "-arg1 -arg2" "some text here"` and `espeak -arg1 -arg2 "some text here"`. In my first example, `-arg1 -arg2` is in quotes; the second one isn't.

Comment: @Drew  
Chronos provides multiple countdown / countup timers, shown sorted by expiry
time in a special buffer *chronos*.  Homepage: http://github.com/dxknight/chronos.

Comment: @Drew The question is to correct chronos-text-to-speech-notify so that he speaks French. I think we need to review chronos - shell-command to send a functional command

Comment: That's not a question; it's a request for (who?) to correct something you think needs correcting. If you do actually have a question, please put it in the posted question, explicitly. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Following a look at [chronos.el](https://github.com/dxknight/chronos/blob/b360d9dae57aa553cf2a14ffa0756a51ad71de09/chronos.el#L180)

> ```
> (setq chronos-text-to-speech-program-parameters 
>       "-s 50 -k 1 -a 50 -v mb/mb-fr1")
> ```

should probably be:

```
(setq chronos-text-to-speech-program-parameters
      '("-s" "50" "-k" "1" "-a" "50" "-v" "mb/mb-fr1"))
```

It looks buggy in that it's not passing the arguments through `shell-quote-argument`, although it's unclear if there's actually any reason to be using `start-process-shell-command` (as opposed to `start-process`).  Either way I suspect there are improvements which could be made upstream.

Comment: thats do not make any change

Comment: It absolutely makes a difference to the shell command which is called.  If you're not seeing the difference in the quoting, then you've not tested correctly.  If you *do* see the difference in the command, yet the outcome is the same, then my assumption about the cause of the problem was incorrect.

Comment: The command *I* see using my suggested change matches the format you've shown after the "This shell command works fine, however" part of the question.

Comment: Ok, whith your suggestion, chronos speak french. sorry for the noise